# How to display an entry on frontend with status disabled if admin is logged in?

Tags: entry, admin, status

Something like this?

```
{% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %}
    {% set slug = craft.request.lastSegment %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug(slug).status(null).first %}
{% endif %}

{{ entry.title }}
```

But I get error page not found.

Comment: Non of this Twig code can cause a 404 page not found error, so you should rather check your [routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing), Johannes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're specifically checking for the admin, then it's more like:

```
{% if currentUser.admin %}
    {% set slug = craft.request.lastSegment %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug(slug).status(null).first %}

    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

If you're getting a 404, then it's some other routing issues that is occurring.

Comment: Looked at apply this to "any" user - {% if user %} but if the entry is disabled then I can't see anything at all.

Tried also 
{% if entry.status == "['disabled', 'live']" %}
STUFF
{% endif %}

but can't get that far.